# Trying to use modal dialog in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `if`/`else` statements inside a function like the following (code below and [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kdk9gj0e/3/)) and I am trying to use a [confirmModal dialog](http://vadimsva.github.io/popModal/) when a user selects the third option from the dropdown menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdownSelectionItem = $("#name").val();
    console.log("Check:" + dropdownSelectionItem);

    if (dropdownSelectionItem == "First") {
        //alert("Are you sure you want to select first option?");
        id_value = 1000;
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Second") {
        id_value = 2000;
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Third") {
        //alert("Are you sure you want to select third option?");
        $('#content').confirmModal({
            topOffset : 0,
            onOkBut : function() {
                id_value = 3000;
            },
            onCancelBut : function() {},
            onLoad : function() {},
            onClose : function() {}
          });
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Fourth") {
        id_value = 4000;
    }
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="name">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>  
    <option value="Fourth">Fourth</option>                                              
</select>

<!-- 
    <button data-confirmmodal-bind="#content" data-topoffset="0" data-top="0">example</button>
-->
```

Why it doesn't work? Is there anything wrong I am doing in using the library? I'm not sure if I want to use the `#content` id as shown in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few issues.

First, as others have mentioned, you were running the script only once on page load, rather than [binding to an event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/) - in this case, the drop-down `change` event.

Second, because your HTML code didn't have any element with an id of `content`, your modal wasn't displaying (because it was set to display `#content`).

As a side-note, this was made obvious by looking at the developer console.  The popscript.js would thrown an error, and by using the tools in the developer's console, I was able to see the issue quickly.  If you don't know how to use your browser's developer's console, [invest in learning how](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/mastering-developer-tools-console)

Here's an [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/kdk9gj0e/8/), and the updated code:

Script:

```
// Shorthand no-conflict safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // Bind the "checkSelection" function to the change of the select dropdown
  $('#name').on('change', checkSelection);

  // The code you had, but put into a function so we can call when we want
  function checkSelection() {
    var dropdownSelectionItem = $("#name").val();
    console.log("Check:" + dropdownSelectionItem);

    if (dropdownSelectionItem == "First") {
      alert("Are you sure you want to select first option?");
      id_value = 1000;
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Second") {
      id_value = 2000;
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Third") {
      alert("Are you sure you want to select third option?");
      $('#content').confirmModal({
        topOffset: 0,
        onOkBut: function() {
          id_value = 3000;
        },
        onCancelBut: function() {},
        onLoad: function() {},
        onClose: function() {}
      });
    } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Fourth") {
      id_value = 4000;
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="name">
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">Second</option>
  <option value="Third">Third</option>
  <option value="Fourth">Fourth</option>
</select>

<!-- Copied straight from the demo for the confirmModal script -->
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <div class="popModal_footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-popmodal-but="ok">ok</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-popmodal-but="cancel">cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event handler for when the dropdown changes. Right now, this JS will only run when the document is loaded. Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdk9gj0e/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change','#name',function(){
         var dropdownSelectionItem = $("#name").val();
         console.log("Check:" + dropdownSelectionItem);

         if (dropdownSelectionItem == "First") {
             alert("Are you sure you want to select first option?");
             id_value = 1000;
         } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Second") {
             id_value = 2000;
         } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Third") {
             alert("Are you sure you want to select third option?");
         $('#content').confirmModal({
            topOffset : 0,
            onOkBut : function() {
                id_value = 3000;
         },
            onCancelBut : function() {},
            onLoad : function() {},
            onClose : function() {}
         });
         } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Fourth") {
            id_value = 4000;
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code just runs once when the document is ready.

What you want to do is create an onchange event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').on('change', dropdownchange);
});




function dropdownchange() {
  var dropdownSelectionItem = $("#name").val();

  console.log("Check:" + dropdownSelectionItem);


  if (dropdownSelectionItem == "First") {
      alert("Are you sure you want to select first option?");
      id_value = 1000;
  } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Second") {
      id_value = 2000;
  } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Third") {
      alert("Are you sure you want to select third option?");
      $('#content').confirmModal({
          topOffset: 0,
          onOkBut: function() {
          id_value = 3000;
      },
      onCancelBut: function() {},
      onLoad: function() {},
      onClose: function() {}
  });
  } else if (dropdownSelectionItem == "Fourth") {
      id_value = 4000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I can see the alert on selecting third option.Could you tell me why confirmModal doesn't works?

Comment: The confirm modal doesn't work because you don't have an HTML element with an id of `content`, so the script doesn't have anything to show.

Comment: Your jsfiddle currently does not have an element with id of "content".  $('#content').confirmModal

Comment: Here is updated JSFiddle and it still doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/kdk9gj0e/13/ . I mean I want to show dialog and not example button as mentioned in the confirmModal tutorial/reference

Answer (score 0):

You are adding this to the onload/load event of your page.

What you need to do is to add it to the event onchange event of the dropdown/select.

```
$(function)() {

    $( "#name" ).change(function() {
          //add your code yere
    });

}
```